# The movie talks about Natasha's past

Tags: word-usage, word-request

Can you say *the movie talks about something* referring to the theme of the film? If not, what would you say instead?

> The movie talks about Natasha's past and all the unfinished business she had before joining the Avengers.

> The movie mentions...

Comment: Another verb you could use is **depicts**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use "the movie talks about". Here are some examples from Google books:
[Google books "the movie talks about"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20movie%20talks%20about%22%20&sca_esv=570352775&tbm=bks&ei=LWccZeCDI6eskdUPraaLyA0&ved=0ahUKEwigzvyqytqBAxUnVqQEHS3TAtkQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22the%20movie%20talks%20about%22%20&gs_lp=Eg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzIhgidGhlIG1vdmllIHRhbGtzIGFib3V0IiBIkDhQiQxY3TRwAXgAkAEAmAHPA6ABuguqAQkwLjEuMi4xLjG4AQPIAQD4AQGIBgE&sclient=gws-wiz-books)

Another example, "the paper discusses":
[Google books "the paper discusses"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20paper%20discusses%22&sca_esv=570352775&tbm=bks&ei=TGccZcKtIKqrkdUPxJGn-Ao&ved=0ahUKEwjCg965ytqBAxWqVaQEHcTICa8Q4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22the%20paper%20discusses%22&gs_lp=Eg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzIhUidGhlIHBhcGVyIGRpc2N1c3NlcyJItSpQxQNYpydwAHgAkAEAmAGVAqABsh6qAQYwLjIuMTW4AQPIAQD4AQHCAgUQABiABMICBRAAGKIEiAYB&sclient=gws-wiz-books)

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. For the average person in their daily life, yes. For an English learner or someone in Academia, no.

While it is common and natural to hear things like "the movie talks about" or "the article says" in informal speech writing, some people --including many of those who evaluate English learners' speaking and writing-- would say movies/articles/etc. don't "speak" or "mention" things, only people do. Rather, *characters, actors, writers and directors* say things or talk about things *in movies*.

Here are some inarguably correct ways of expressing that idea with a movie/book/etc. as the subject:

> The article *addresses* issues surrounding homelessness and addiction.
> The book *speaks to* the difficulty of raising a child alone.
> The movie *is about* monks in Thailand.

All these expressions apply to slightly different situations. If you want to say a movie includes some specific information, "*gives*", "*explains*", "*reveals*", "*hints at*" and "*teases*" are common and natural. So for your example, you might put it like this:

> The movie *reveals* Natasha's past and all the unfinished business...